# how to use loop function to add column heading and row heading

Tags: plotting, excel, infinite-loop

I have a raw data xsl file without heading column and column heading
[image]

I want the A,B,C....J to be question 1, question2.....question J and 1,2,3 ....n to be participant 1, participant2, ......participant n, so I can use TableForm function, how can I do that?

Comment: `TableHeadings` option of `TableForm`

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

[image: dataset]

```
raw = Flatten[Import @ "C:\\Users\\-e\\Documents\\data.xlsx", 1]
data = Prepend[raw,{"First", "Second", "Third", "Forth"}]

Grid[data, Frame -> All]
```

**Output:**

[image: column headers output]

**EDIT**

In order to have both row and column headers you could do something like this, see example below...

**Example:**

```
(*row and column headers*)
columnHeader = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Forth"};
rowHeader = {"", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"};

(*process*)
data = MapThread[Prepend, {Prepend[raw, columnHeader], rowHeader}]
```

**Output:**

```
Grid[data, Frame -> All]
```

[image: rows and columns with headers]

**Reference:**

[Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)
[Import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html?q=Import)
[Prepend](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prepend.html)
[Grid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html)

**Tutorial:**

[Put Headings in a Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PutHeadingsInATable.html)